# Expectation of CDF of normal random variable.

Tags: integration, statistics

Let $\Phi$ be the CDF of the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$.
Then can we analytically compute $E(\Phi(y-c))$, where $y$ follows $N(0,1)$ and $c>0$? I need this for my research in social science. I know it is 1/2 if $c=0$, but I would like to obtain it for $c>0$.

Comment: @Arkamis: The expectation of $\Phi(x)$, the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, is indeed $\frac12$, by symmetry since $\Phi(-x)+\Phi(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Henry Ah yes, I misread that, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(z)$ represent the density of a standard normal random variable.  We begin by making the observation that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\left[\Phi(y-c)\right] = - f(y-c).$$  Then consider $$g(c) = \operatorname{E}[\Phi(Y-c)] = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \Phi(y-c) f(y) \, dy,$$ hence $$g'(c) = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty -f(y-c)f(y) \, dy = - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-c^2/4}.$$  That is to say, $g'(c)$ is the negative of a normal density with mean $0$ and variance $2$.  It follows that $$g(c) = \int g'(c) \, dc = -\Phi \left( \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}} \right) + C,$$ where $C$ is a constant of integration.  But since we can reason by way of symmetry that $g(0) = 1/2$, we find $C = 1$; therefore $$g(c) = \Phi\left(-\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Comment: Nice to see a proof of my empirical result